# click multiple elements to hide or show something - jquery

Tags: javascript, function, hide, bind, show

here is my script. Now i can click one of these IDs and class "inputs" are visible. What i want is that I have to click on all elements.

```
$('#zwei,#sechs,#neun').bind('click', function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.inputs').show();
    } else {
        $('.inputs').hide();
    }
});
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/CLYC6/20/

can you help me please? whats wrong?

FK

Comment: You mean on all 3 elements( with id "#zwei,#sechs,#neun")  click event should be triggered at once? then call `$('#zwei,#sechs,#neun').click();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('#zwei,#sechs,#neun').bind('click', function() {
    $('.inputs').show();
    $('#zwei,#sechs,#neun').each(function (e) {
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.inputs').hide();
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/CLYC6/22/).

Because @Rastko is not happy with the current solution here is one more:

```
$('#zwei,#sechs,#neun').bind('click', function() {
    var showInput = true;
    $('#zwei,#sechs,#neun').each(function (e) {
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            showInput = false;
            return;
        }
    });
    if (showInput) {
        $('.inputs').show();
    } else {
        $('.inputs').hide();
    }
});
```

One more [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/CLYC6/24/).

Comment: The final outcome of this will most probably be what he asked for, but this is inverse solution... Inputs should always stay hidden until shown by the condition... this is matter of UX. If you show it first, something can make a glich in js and your process is broken.

Also, you have a loop that will go through each checkbox and test it  sequentially applying hide or not applying hide... When you can use single if statement to just show it whenever you need to.

Comment: The input is hidden :-) And the result is exactly what he asked for :-)

Comment: On click, you show it every time and then hide it again after going through the sequence of checking all checkboxes

Comment: I added one more solution which will make you happy :-)

Comment: But don't be so angry by putting down votes to working and elegant solutions :-)

Comment: if($('#zvei').is(':checked') && $('#neun').is(':checked') && $('#sechs').is(':checked') {
      $('.inputs').show();
  }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28713/discussion-between-minko-gechev-and-rastko)

Comment: This aint facebok :D I am not "angry", I just see missleading and not optimal solution for such a simple interaction.

Comment: What happens when you have 200 checkboxes and you select them not by id but by class name? How will look your if statement in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If statement should check whether all three are checked, and if input is not visible.

so:

```
if($('#zvei').is(':checked') && $('#neun').is(':checked') && $('#sechs').is(':checked') {
      $('.inputs').show();
  }
```